# Dark Souls 2 Undead Crypt Question

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm at the Undead Crypt

> just after the Undead Ditch bonfire. Dropping down the hole in the ground, and hollow zombies keep ringing that damn bell. Even if I kill them and carry on, by the time I get to the fog gate it rings and rings and spawns a ton of casters making life unpleasant.

Can I stop this from happening at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you enter the long hallway before the fog gate you will be on top of some stairs. Instead of running right down them fall to either side. There is an opening under the stairs where a zombie rings the bell as long as he is alive. Kill him and the bell will not ring at all during your trip down the hallway to the boss! Be careful not to hit the bell while killing him though as this will spawn enemies.